# ExecuteNonQuery on a stored proc causes it to be deleted

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is a strange one.   I have a Dev SQL Server which has the stored proc on it, and the same stored proc when used with the same code on the UAT DB causes it to delete itself!

Has anyone heard of this behaviour?

**SQL Code**:

```
-- Check if user is registered with the system
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_is_valid_user') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user
  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_is_valid_user') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user >>>'
  ELSE
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user >>>'
END
go

create procedure dbo.sp_is_valid_user

@username as varchar(20),
@isvalid as int OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

    declare @tmpuser as varchar(20) 

    select @tmpuser = username from CPUserData where username = @username

    if @tmpuser = @username
        BEGIN
        select @isvalid = 1
        END
    else
    BEGIN
    select @isvalid = 0
        END

END
GO
```

Usage example

```
DECLARE @isvalid int
exec dbo.sp_is_valid_user 'username', @isvalid OUTPUT
SELECT valid = @isvalid
```

The usage example work all day... when I access it via C# it deletes itself in the UAT SQL DB but not the Dev one!!

**C# Code**:

```
    public bool IsValidUser(string sUsername, ref string sErrMsg)
    {
        string sDBConn = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StoredProcDBConnection"];

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sDBConn);
            sqlcmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "sp_is_valid_user";

            // params to pass in 
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", sUsername);

            // param for checking success passed back out 
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@isvalid", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlcmd.Parameters["@isvalid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int nIsValid = (int)sqlcmd.Parameters["@isvalid"].Value;

            if (nIsValid == 1)
            {
                conn.Close();
                sErrMsg = "User Valid";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                sErrMsg = "Username : " + sUsername + " not found.";
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            sErrMsg = "Error :" + e.Source + " msg: " + e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're usage example is calling a different proc "sp_is_user_admin" than your c# code.  Also, you might want to investigate the USING keyword in c#.  This code can leak connections all over the place.

Comment: Your procedure could be simplified to "set @isvalid = 0; select @isvalid = 1 from CPUserData where username = @username;" thus not requiring a temporary variable. Also, consider moving conn.Close() to a finally block.

Comment: @ Chris.. I have just changed that to sp_is_valid_user, thanks.. sadly not the problem solved though :(

Comment: Seems like a long-shot, but since you are doing a drop-create when adding the sproc, I would check that the drop code didn't accidentally get copy/pasted into the body of the procedure. Could have been a bad copy paste job, or something else. Are you saving your DB create scripts? Can you run the scripts to recreate the DB on your development machine and see if it gets replicated?

Comment: Its not the drop scripts... thanks for the tip but I have already removed that just in case.... I also stated in the question I think that I can run it via the usage example all day no problem, so that would show it up if there was a drop statement.  Its only coming in through C# that causes the problem.

Comment: Is the name of the person you are trying to validate "Peggy O'Drop Procedure dbo.sp_is_valid_user"?

Comment: @NerdFury...  ha ha, no its not SQL injection.  Cheers for the thought tack.. I'm going to answer my own question now as I google away and found something on another question here on stackoverflow. It will make sense when I post the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer ... simple when you know how!

I saw this link here :

Disappearing Stored Procedure

[Disappearing Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858648/disappearing-stored-procedure/858890#858890)

So from the best answer in that I ran :

```
select syo.name
from syscomments syc
  join sysobjects syo on
    syo.id = syc.id
where syc.[text] like '%DROP PROC%'
```

This gave me one of my OTHER stored procs back... sp_is_user_admin, which didn't seem right so I had a quick look ...

```
create procedure dbo.sp_is_user_admin
@username as varchar(20),
@isadmin as int OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @profile as varchar(20)

    select @profile = profile from CPUserData where username = @username

    if @profile = 'admin'
        BEGIN
        select @isadmin = 1
        END
    else
        BEGIN
        select @isadmin = 0
        END

END

--*********************************************************************************

-- Check if user is registered with the system
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_is_valid_user') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_is_valid_user') IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user >>>'
    ELSE
        PRINT '<<< DROPPED PROCEDURE dbo.sp_is_valid_user >>>'
END
```

Doh!!!   There is the blighter... in the C# what happens is that if the user is valid I also choose what to let them see based on if they are admin or not and calling that was blitzing the sp_is_valid_user proc.  Nasty side effect!

```
// check the user is entitled to use the system at all 
if (usrData.IsValidUser(sCurrentUserName, ref sErrMsg))
{
    // if the user is admin then let them spoof and edit their own data 
    if (usrData.UserIsAdmin(sCurrentUserName, ref sErrMsg))
    {
        chkSpoof.Visible = true;
        grdvwUserDataFromDB.Visible = true;
    }
}
else
{
    // redirect them away
    Response.Redirect("UserNotRegistered.aspx");
    return;

}
```

I hope this helps someone else out!

PS: DB Artisan is **nasty** and if I had the full fat SQL Server available in my Development toolkit then I guess I could have used the profiler to see this being called.  ;P I can't install SQL Server 2008 as I don't have the right SP / updates to Visual Studio I think and IT here can't sort it out, annoying!!